# trying to run a function within a class

Tags: php, class, oop

I am trying to call a function within my class. But when i try to call it errors out and says "Fatal error: Call to undefined function" even though its defined within my class.

```
 function checkArray($day, $array){
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (array_search($day, $value)) 
        return $key;  
     }
    return false; 
}
```

And i try to call it like this within another function of the class

```
if(checkArray($i,$events)){
echo $events[checkArray($i,$events)]["short"];
}
```

if i test this code without using a class, it works perfect. But within a class it seems like it doesn't let me call a function that is within a class. I'm kind of new to OOP so i know it might seem like a dumb question.

Comment: In a class, you need to call the function with the `->` operator.  If it's in the same class, then you probably want `$this->checkArray($i, $events)`.

Comment: yeah but if i don't return $key how can i get it?

Comment: so which one are you saying to remove the return $key; or the return false;

Comment: @Brad Ignore him, there's nothing to remove.

Comment: I changed the function to this, but it doesn't return anything

Comment: function checkArray($day, $array){
      foreach ($array as $key => $value)
      {
          if (array_search($day, $value)) {
     $in = $key;
    }else{
     $in = false; 
    }
      
       }
       return $in; 
  }

Comment: @BradHazelnut No, this will overwrite the already found key. I think your code in the question is abs. ok in this point!

Comment: Sorry, should have read the code better. Removing the comment now so it can't confuse others. Thank you all for correcting my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $this->checkArray($i, $events).  The important bit being $this-> as you are calling it from within a class.  If it's a static method, use self::checkArray($i, $events);